# Apache Drill: Group by week

Tags: datetime, aggregate, apache-drill

I tried to group my daily data by week (given a reference date) to generate a smaller panel data set.

I used postgres before and there it was quite easy:

```
CREATE TABLE videos_weekly AS SELECT channel_id,
CEIL(DATE_PART('day', observation_date - '2016-02-10')/7) AS week
FROM videos GROUP BY channel_id, week;
```

But it seems like it is not possible to subtract a timestamp with a date string in Drill. I found the `AGE` function, which returns an interval between two dates, but how to convert this into an integer (number of days or weeks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE_SUB may help you here. Following is an example:

```
SELECT extract(day from date_sub('2016-11-13', cast('2015-01-01' as timestamp)))/7 FROM (VALUES(1));
```

This will return number of weeks between 2015-01-01 and 2016-11-13.

[Click here for documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/#date_sub)